# multiple colorboxes in iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox

I want to stack 2 or 3 colorboxes on top of each other, but not within each other's bounds like Russian Dolls, more like the first one covers 50% of the screen, the second one covers 100% of the screen, and then the third one covers 50% of the screen again.

I have managed to create the effect, with some help from [here](http://metaflood.com/work-life/how-to-use-the-jquery-plugin-colorbox-from-within-an-iframe/), but the problem is that when I close the colorbox, all currently open colorboxes close at the same time. I want the close button just to close that colorbox. In theory people will be closing them in order, but I can't predict that obviously.

I presume this is something to do with jquery selectors closing all open colorboxes. Any pointers appreciated.

Code to create first colorbox:

```
  $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:width, height:height, scrolling: false, href:linkRef, fastIframe:false, onClosed:function(){$('#cboxClose').attr('class', '');}});
  $('#cboxClose').attr('class', 'photomontageFrame');
```

Code to create second colorbox:

```
 window.parent.$.colorbox({iframe:true, width:width, height:height, scrolling: false, href:a, onClosed:function(){$('#cboxClose').attr('class', '');}});
 window.parent.$('#cboxClose').attr('class', 'photomontageFrame');
```

Thanks

Comment: Am I missing something or you did not provide any code / fiddle?

Comment: You're right, I didn't - was in too much of a hurry

Comment: Maybe a full html structure + the code you provided, all in a fiddle, would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think your issue is iframe, it is the fact that colorbox only supports one instance. It also seems like a very old plugin, does not support newest versions of jQuery. I would look for a different plugin.

Comment: The tutorial on the link is old, but `colorbox()` is probably the best maintained modal plugin out there, imo!

Comment: Seems strange that it does not support jQuery 1.9 or 2.0, due to browser checks. But okay, the big problem is that you can not have more than one colorbox at any time I believe.

Comment: Well if you're using the demo on the tutorial link, that uses a colorbox version `1.3.*` whereas the current [`1.5.1`](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox) which I believe fixed any issues with 1.9 in the past. (Sorry if you weren't), but I believe you're correct about one instance.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that explains it :-) Good luck on finding a plugin that gives you the functionality you want!

Comment: Wish I had known that when I chose colorbox! Don't suppose anyone has any other suggestions?